# Uses of serialization in a web application

Tags: javascript, serialization

I'm teaching JS my self and I just been reading about objects [JavaScript Objects in Detail](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-objects-in-detail/) which also discuss object serialization. So I tired to read more about that in order to understand the concept and to find a real use. So I found many tutorials on how to use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`, but I still can't come up with a scenario when I would need to serialize an objecct. The only one scenario I've used so far was to serialize a from with `jQuery` in order to sent data with `.post()`, but I'm not to sure if this is related.

What are the most common scenarios for serializing an object in a web application?

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of scenarios, the most useful I can think of is when you want to store the data offline ( for example mobile or desktop application), you can use `localStorage` to store the serialized data (using `JSON.stringify()`) and load it back by parsing it into object (using `JSON.parse()`).

This offline storing of data is useful when the user don't have internet access and the user still wants to see already fetched items.

**Note:**
You can find more info at below references:

1. [localStorage Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)
2. [How to use local storage](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/)

Comment: So, for example I could save partially completed HTML form to be completed in the future. Would that be a good case for using serialization ?

Comment: You can save only serialized objects. Once you parse it to JSON, you can create any sort of UI you need.